# How to combine these FFMPEG command?

Tags: ffmpeg

> Add logo

```
ffmpeg -i mainVideo.mp4 -i logo.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+36/TB[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass[out1]" -map [out1] -threads 5 -y main_with_logo.mp4
```

> Remove voice

```
ffmpeg -i main_with_logo.mp4 -c:v copy -an main_with_logo_s.mp4 -y
```

> Add Speaker Voice

```
ffmpeg -i main_with_logo_s.mp4 -i voice.mp3 -filter:a "volume=2.5" -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 4400k -vf fps=25 -c:a aac -strict experimental main_with_logo_voice.mp4 -y -threads 5
```

> Add BGM

```
ffmpeg -i main_with_logo_voice.mp4 -i bgm.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2 -y -threads 5 main_with_logo_voice_bgm.mp4
```

> Add Subtitle

```
ffmpeg -i main_with_logo_voice_bgm.mp4 -vf "subtitles=main.srt:force_style='Fontname=jx,Fontsize=16'" -threads 5 -y main_with_logo_voice_bgm_srt.mp4
```

All these step takes long time , how can i combine these cmd to one or two ?

Answer (score 1):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i mainVideo.mp4 -i logo.mov -i voice.mp3 -i bgm.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+36/TB[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass,subtitles=main.srt:force_style='Fontname=jx,Fontsize=16',format=yuv420p;[2:a]volume=2.5[voice];[voice][3:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" output.mp4
```